# Problem with CSV file creation in java with opencsv

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am trying to write a data from database to a csv file via java thread. For writing i am making use of OPENCSV jar. The problem i am facing is that sometimes in csv file values get corrupted like shown below in line 1 and 4.
I have no idea as to why this is happening. Values coming from the database are all ok (as can be seen in the logs) but in csv file its not.

```
[E[EcoUnit 01]  [Segment B/1]   [2017-12-29 22:13:23.047]   [ventilation air humidity]  [70.18]
[EcoUnit 01]    [Segment B/1]   [2017-10-25 22:21:36.583]   [ventilation air humidity]  [69.65]
[EcoUnit 01]    [Segment B/1]   [2017-10-25 22:22:36.59]    [ventilation air humidity]  [69.33]
[EcoUnit 01]    [Segment B/017-11-14 12:02:48.013]  [ventilation fan]   [30]
```

I would be really grateful if anyone can let me suggest why this is happening.
Code is as follows: -

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                    fw = new FileWriter(file);
                    writer = new CSVWriter(fw); 
                    writer.writeNext(headers);
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Unit_Label").toString());
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Segment_Label").toString());
                    values.add("[" + doc.getFieldValue("datestring").toString() + "]");
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Item_Label").toString());
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Value").toString());
                    writer.writeNext(values.toArray(new String[]{}));
```

Adding complete code of the function responsible for creating file and writing into it.

```
public void createAndFillFile(String startDateStr, String endDateStr, int fileNumber,SolrDocumentList results){
        try{
            String startDateParts[] = startDateStr.split(" ");
            String startDate  = startDateParts[0];
            String endDateParts[] = endDateStr.split(" ");
            String endDate  = endDateParts[0];
            if(fileNumber == 1){

                Date date = new Date() ;
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") ;

                String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date); //This line can be removed and in below line directly can be used
                zipFile = currentDate + ".zip";

                dir = new File("C:" + File.separator + "EcotronDownloadable" + File.separator + currentDate);


                dir.mkdir();

                path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator ;
                file = new File(path+ startDate + "_" + endDate + "_" + fileNumber + ".csv");
                fw = new FileWriter(file);
                writer = new CSVWriter(fw);
                writer.writeNext(headers);

            }
            synchronized(file){
            for (SolrDocument doc : results) {
                List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                Thread.sleep(1);
                long fileLength = file.length();
                if(fileLength<maxFileSize){
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Unit_Label").toString());
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Segment_Label").toString());
                    values.add("[" + doc.getFieldValue("datestring").toString() + "]");
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Item_Label").toString());
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Value").toString());
                    //log.trace(values);
                    writer.writeNext(values.toArray(new String[]{}));
                }
                else{
                    fw.flush();
                    fw.close();
//                  writer.close();
                    j = j + 1;
                    file = new File(path + startDate + "_" + endDate  + "_" + j + ".csv") ;
                    fw = new FileWriter(file);
                    writer = new CSVWriter(fw); 
                    writer.writeNext(headers);
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Unit_Label").toString());
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Segment_Label").toString());
                    values.add("[" + doc.getFieldValue("datestring").toString() + "]");
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Item_Label").toString());
                    values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Value").toString());
                    //log.trace(values);
                    writer.writeNext(values.toArray(new String[]{}));

                }
            }
            }

//          fw.flush();
//          fw.close();
//          writer.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

``
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have two FileWriter instances (in different threads) pointing to the same file and writing at same time.

try this:

```
    synchronized (file)
    {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        fw = new FileWriter(file);
        writer = new CSVWriter(fw);
        writer.writeNext(headers);
        values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Unit_Label").toString());
        values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Segment_Label").toString());
        values.add("[" + doc.getFieldValue("datestring").toString() + "]");
        values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Item_Label").toString());
        values.add(doc.getFieldValue("Value").toString());
        writer.writeNext(values.toArray(new String[]{}));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply but still same problem. Synchronized the file but same results`

Comment: Added complete code for the function responsible for the creation of file and writing into the file in the question.

Comment: @nehag -  I see know you left part of the writing (                writer.writeNext(headers)) out of the synchronized block. Check it out